# Robotframework: log.html and report.html not created (pool.apply_async add "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" in output.xml)

Tags: python, robotframework, python-multiprocessing

**The problom**:
`log.html` and `report.html` are not created after script ends, it end with this error message:

> [ ERROR ] Reading XML source '/Users/adikeller/Applications/GIT/BeAm/output.xml' failed: ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 96, column 357

**The symptom**
I'm using `pool.apply_async` (asynchronous threading) in my python script, and after massive debugging I notice that when all threads are done "< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >" is added to `output.xml` (at the end of line number in the error message) which probably cause the error.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.num_of_workers)
results = [pool.apply_async(ThrdMultiBcons.shoot_beacons, args=(x, timeDelta, end_req, is_random,)) for x in range(1,self.num_of_workers+1)]
```

**Additional info**:
I notice in output.xml file that "< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >" is actually cut "< robot > ... < /robot >" at the middle and create new "< robot >" line which cause the whole mess:

```
<robot ...
:
<msg ... </msg>
<msg ... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot ...
...
...
</robot>
```

Any idea what can be done in order solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi,any solution to this issue?i also face same

Comment: Happens to me too, the test suite started failing after I updated my python libraries. The XML is "re-started" just after a [`Builtin.Sleep`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Sleep), but there may be some threading stuff in the background.